# Is there a way to animate a button on click with classList.add?

Tags: javascript, css, button, onclick, css-animations

I have recently learned that one way to make an animation play on button click, is to append an animation class to it with `myObject.classList.add('animationClass')`. This method however, works only for the first time the button is clicked - since the animation class remains in the HTML object.

I figured, that if I use `myObject.classList.Remove('animationClass')` at the start of the function, I could achieve repeatability with my button.

After playing around with the function, it seemed that whenever I implement the line to remove the class, the line to add it gets overridden and no animation is played.

Here is the code I tried at first:

```js
myButton = document.getElementById('switchButton')
myButton.classList.remove('animationClass'); //remove the class, from previous clicks
myButton.classList.add('animationClass'); //add the class to play animation
```

```css
.animationClass {
  animation: rotate forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="" id="switchButton" onclick="switchFunction()">Switch</button>
```

I then tried implementing `myObject.classList.remove` with a delay using `setTimeout`, but to no avail.

```
JS
myObject.classList.add('animationClass');
setTimeout(function(){myObject.classList.remove('animationClass')},2s);
```

Comment: Where is the click listener?

Comment: You can't use 2s with setTimeout, use a Number in milliseconds -> 2000

Comment: @Barmar new to this, in my original code i used it in the HTML element with onClick. Thanks! also, how do you create a code snipplet?

Answer (score 0):

You basically just have a small mistake. You have to write `2000` (milliseconds) instead of `2s`.

However, I would recommend you to use the `animationend`-Listener.

### Your approach

```js
switchFunction = function() {
  myButton=document.getElementById('switchButton')
  myButton.classList.add('animationClass'); //add the class to play animation
  setTimeout(function(){myButton.classList.remove('animationClass')}, 2000);
}
```

```css
.animationClass{
    animation: rotate forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate{
    0%{transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<button class="" id="switchButton" onclick="switchFunction()">Switch</button>
```

### Using a Listener

```js
myButton=document.getElementById('switchButton')

myButton.addEventListener("animationend", () => myButton.classList.remove('animationClass'));

switchFunction = () => myButton.classList.add('animationClass'); //add the class to play animation
```

```css
.animationClass{
    animation: rotate forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate{
    0%{transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<button class="" id="switchButton" onclick="switchFunction()">Switch</button>
```